# SQLite Query with COUNT and ID string

Tags: python, sqlite

First... i have a SQLite database:

```
I have an user table tbl_members
member_id
name
```

```
and an order table tbl_orders
order_id
member_ids
name
```

An order can be edited by more than one member and this members are stored in tbl_orders member_ids in this fashion 1,2,34,23,65,

I need a query that returns:

```
tbl_members.member_id, tbl_members.name and a COUNT(tbl_orders.order_id) of the orders where the tbl.members.member_id is in tbl.orders.member_ids
```

I can't get it... can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

is this your expected answer?

```
SELECT tm.member_id, tm.name, COUNT(to.order_id)
FROM tbl_members as tm
LEFT JOIN tbl_orders as to on tm.member_id = to.member_id
GROUP BY tm.member.id, tm.name
```

Comment: not exactly because to.member_ids contains a list of ids like 1,2,5,6,34,23,

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

```
SELECT tm.member_id, tm.name, COUNT(to.order_id) 
FROM tbl_members tm 
LEFT JOIN tbl_orders to ON (to.member_ids LIKE '%,'||tm.member_id||'%') 
GROUP BY tm.member_id
```

Works for me